# Resources on Jablon's Protocol

Tags: cr.crypto-security, security

Are there any good resources (descriptions, explanations, examples) regarding Jablon's **protocol for password authentication using multiple servers**, aside from [this paper](http://www.jablon.org/jab01.pdf)?

Comment: some more detail on this protocol please ?

Comment: see linked paper for details: http://www.jablon.org/jab01.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the book [Protocols for Authentication and Key Establishment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540431071) very promising on the subject of authentication protocols. Specifically, it references two protocols by Jablon (see references 165 and 166 of the book).

You may also find more info in [papers that cite Jablon's Protocol](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=6764030118523462813&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=2000&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of papers on the general topic of password authentification on this web page:

http://www.jablon.org/passwordlinks.html